# GitHub API v4 authentification

Tags: angular, authentication, github-api, apollo

I have generated a token from GitHub and I would like to use GitHub API v4 but I have to be authenticated first. I tried this code:

```
const networkInterface = createBatchingNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
  batchInterval: 10
});
```

And I have an error

```
This endpoint requires you to be authenticated.
```

So I am trying to authentificate with my token but it does not work. I tried in example to do like that:

```
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};  // Create the header object if needed.
    }
    req.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'mytokenishere';
    next();
  }
}]);
```

and in this case I receive an information:

```
Bad credentials
```

I also tried to do this in other ways but it doesn't  work.

Comment: Is your `Authorization` header just `mytokenishere` or is it `bearer mytokenishere`?

Comment: Hmm, it is only mytokenishere.

Comment: Try including `bearer` as the token type with your token. The GitHub v4 API documentation makes reference to it here: https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql, and I'm assuming `Bad credentials` indicates it isn't reading it correctly since you don't include a token type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the type of the token like this.

```
  setNetworkInterface(): void{
        networkInterface.use([{
          applyMiddleware(req, next) {
            if (!req.options.headers) {
              req.options.headers = {}; 
            }
            req.options.headers.authorization = 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX';
            req.options.headers.host = 'https://api.github.com/graphql';
            next();
          }
        }]);
      }
```